# Using Spirit x3, how to control which parser is called on each different input?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I'm working with boost spirit x3 and am unclear on one point. I have a file that has very different and repetitive lines. The first few lines may be comments. The next 1000 lines may be coordinates, the next thousand lines may be a list of int's, etc...

My question is how to recognize the line and know which parser to use for that line. E.g., here are two parser functions ....

```
template <typename Iterator>
bool parse_ints(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::vector<int>& v)
{
    using x3::int_;
    using x3::phrase_parse;
    using x3::_attr;   
    using ascii::space;

    auto push_back = [&](auto& ctx){ v.push_back(_attr(ctx)); };

    bool r = phrase_parse(first, last,
        (
            int_[push_back]
                >> *(',' >> int_[push_back])
        )
        ,
        space);

    if (first != last) 
        return false;
    return r;
}

template <typename Iterator>
bool parse_doubles(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::vector<double>& v)
{
    using x3::double_;
    using x3::phrase_parse;
    using x3::_attr;
    using ascii::space;

    auto push_back = [&](auto& ctx){ v.push_back(_attr(ctx)); };

    bool r = phrase_parse(first, last,
        (
            double_[push_back]
                >> *(',' >> double_[push_back])
        )
        ,
        space);

    if (first != last) // fail if we did not get a full match
        return false;
    return r;
}
```

And here is how the input comes in (istringstream is hundreds of MB's in size). And within the while loop is how I'm wondering to know which parser to call.

```
int main()
{
    istringstream str(my.data());

    while (getline(str, line)) {
        // based on the format of 'line', how does one know which 
        // parser to call?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar could describe the whole input. So you could say

```
auto input = *headerComment 
          >> points 
          >> edges;
```

Where you could simply define

```
auto headerComment = '#' >> *(char_ - eol) >> eol;
```

And e.g.

```
auto points = skip(blank) [ 
     *(point >> eol)
   ];

auto edges = skip(blank) [ 
     *(edge >> eol)
   ];

point = int_ >> int_ >> int_; // assuming x y z
edge  = int_ >> int_;         // assuming from to
```

This assumes that the input format is unambiguous. I.e. it wouldn't work if points were `x y` only because it's not distinguishable from an edge then.